# How to spatial join points attributes to layer with two (or more) overlapping buffers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, buffer

I'm working with QGIS 1.8 and I've got 3 layers : 2 points layers, and 1 layer composed of the buffers of one of the points layer.

I'd like to retrieve the informations, for the point layer that isn't buffered, of the buffers.

The problem is that some buffers overlap, and some points of the layer I'd like to spatially join are contained within those overlaps.

How can I get the attributes, in my point layer, of those *n* buffers ?

Comment: When you say you want the attributes of those buffers : are this attributes quantitative ? Do you want a mean/sum of them ?

Or if they are qualitative (eg. ID field), how would you have your remaining table ? One column per each attribute of each point ?

Comment: No, buffers are assigned to points from layer one (they are constantly buffers within 100 meters of the point). So I am anxious to get at the data points belonging to the area supported by another point.